# Why are "<" , ">" , " and ' shown in this XML example?

Tags: xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<programme>
    <condition> if (a>b) and (c>d) echo "sorry"; </condition>
</programme>
```

> Result : Success
>
> Document successfully checked

And no errors!! But I read that I can't use special characters directly in XML, but I should pass by entities (example: > ===> `&gt;`, etc.)

Why aren't any errors shown?

But when I try this example (just adding two parentheses) an error is displayed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<programme>
    <condition> if ( a<b and b>d ) </condition>
</programme>
```

> error : 'b' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 3,
>   position 30.

Is this because we open a tag `<b` so it considers and likes an attribute without a value and tag not closed, so is that why the problem exists?

If yes, I can make a conclusion that we can use special characters normally if we don’t make this mistake, right?

Comment: You have to escape characters. Read this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, there's no confusion with `>` character in your example (it's usually the case within the text node): it's just cannot be treated as the end of tag (as there's no corresponding `<` symbol). That's why parser deals with it.

Here's what [the XML FAQ](http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html) says about it:

> Apart from the invisible ASCII control characters (the ones you can't
>   type), all other characters are just normal text. Currency signs (€,
>   £, $, ƒ, ₨, Ƀ, and others), all the punctuation (**except `<` and `&`**), and
>   all other letters, signs, and symbols in any language or writing
>   system are just text (assuming you have the correct character
>   encoding).

---

As for the error, look closely at its text:

```
'b' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 3, position 30.
```

The point it, it's not the first `b` - but the second one. Here's one possible way of how `<b and b>` is treated by the parser:

- `<b` is treated as the opening tag
- `and` is treated as the attribute name

... and now the parser waits for `=` token to appear somewhere, as normal attribute syntax is `%ATTR_NAME% = %ATTR_VALUE%`, with whitespace allowed as a separator. But it gets `b` instead - and just throws hands up in the sky.

Comment: very complete answer , as a useful add , excessive use of entities could slow document , for that we can use CDATA sections .

Comment: example : 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<programme>
    <condition> <![CDATA[if ((a<b) && (c>b) ) echo "c'est bon";]]> </condition>
</programme>